# How to add a secondary output in a Symfony2 Console application?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony2 Console application with a few commands:

```php
$application = new Application();

$application->add(new MyCommand1());
$application->add(new MyCommand2());

$application->run();
```

When running the application, I'd like the output to be redirected both to the console **and** to a file.

I can use [StreamOutput](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/StreamOutput.html) for this, but it looks like I can only provide such an output object if I manually run one of the commands:

```php
$input = ...;
$output = new StreamOutput(fopen('output.log', 'a'));

$command = new MyCommand1();
$command->run($input, $output);
```

But this is not what I want.

**Is it possible to add a secondary output to the `Application` itself?** So that all commands output both to the console, and to a file.

Comment: you can use monolog to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this task, I would create my own Output.

```
class MultipleOutput implements OutputInterface
{
    protected $outputs = array();

    public function __construct(array $outputs = array())
    {
        $this->setOutputs($outputs);
    }

    public function setOutputs(array $outputs = array())
    {
        foreach ($outputs as $output) {
            $this->addOutput($outputs);
        }
    }

    public function addOutput(OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->outputs[] = $output;
    }

    public function write($messages, $newline = false, $type = self::OUTPUT_NORMAL)
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            $output->write($messages, $newline, $type);
        }
    }

    public function writeln($messages, $type = self::OUTPUT_NORMAL)
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            $output->writeln($messages, $type);
        }
    }

    public function setVerbosity($level)
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            $output->setVerbosity($level);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns only the first one
     */
    public function getVerbosity()
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            return $output->getVerbosity();
        }
    }

    public function setDecorated($decorated)
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            $output->setDecorated($decorated);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns only the first one
     */
    public function isDecorated()
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            return $output->isDecorated();
        }
    }

    public function setFormatter(OutputFormatterInterface $formatter)
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            $output->setFormatter($formatter);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns only the first one
     */
    public function getFormatter()
    {
        foreach ($this->outputs as $output) {
            return $output->getFormatter();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your application

```
$application = new Application();

$application->add(new MyCommand1());
$application->add(new MyCommand2());

$output = new MultipleOutput(array(new StreamOutput, new ConsoleOutput));

$application->run(new ArgvInput, $output);
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed the fact that you could actually pass an Output to `Application::run()`!

Comment: This `MultipleOutput` would probably be useful in Symfony by the way, what about a pull request?

Comment: @Benjamin I might give a try sooner or later!